# TLS contact - Keep My Passport added service

Tags: visas, uk, passports, uk-residents

I applied in the **Prague** TLS centre for a certificate of entitlement to the right of abode in the UK and I payed for the added service **Keep My Passport**. I have now received a feedback on my application from Liverpool and was then further instructed by TLS contact to send my passport to them - but to Belgrade in **Serbia**!!
Has this happend to you? I don't feel comfortable sending my passport to Serbia with no furter information as to how, when and most importantly where is my passport going to be sent back to me. And no one is communicating with me from the Prague office.

Comment: This isn't out of the ordinary, all immigration services have trended toward mass-centralisation

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Yes but to a third party country? especially from an EU country to non-EU for a UK visa

Comment: Since the Serbs need visas to enter the UK and the Czechs don't, it's not a surprise to me that the Prague centre is quite small and offloads some agenda elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

All UK visa passport processing in Europe is centralised. For Western Europe, this is in Berlin and for Eastern Europe it's Belgrade. Regardless of whether you'd chosen Keep My Passport, it would have gone there anyway.

You can send it by whatever courier service you prefer. It will be returned to you by courier.